# distinguish one page from other in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think the title is misleading..as i couldnt think of an appropiate title.

I have 4 webpages which i want to demo..

```
[page1] [page2] [page3] [page4]
```

What I want is.. on top of all my pages.. have like 4 of these "buttons" (or something else)

When I am on page 1..page 1 button is bold and rest of the three are light..
When I am on page 2.. page 2 button is bold and so on..

And that each of them link to each other.

Any suggestions

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Why not add an id to the `body`of each page and then test against that in jQuery? Do you have some code to build upon?

Comment: why not put active kind of class on links specific to page. `if user is at 'page1' add active to 'page1 link'` (on default `all are light`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>

button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #123d54;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #afd9fa 0%,
        #588fad);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#afd9fa),
        to(#588fad));
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #003366;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.7),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }

button.current {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #faafaf 0%,
        #d11919);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#faafaf),
        to(#d11919));
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #003366;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.7),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
</style>

<a href="/page1.html">
    <button class="current">Demo Page 1</button>
</a>

<a href="/page1.html">
    <button class="">Demo Page 2</button>
</a>

<a href="/page1.html">
    <button class="">Demo Page 3</button>
</a>

<a href="/page1.html">
    <button class="">Demo Page 4</button>
</a>
```

copy the above at the top of each page you have, for the first page, the button class should be current, for the second one the second button should be current and so forth.

The buttons were generated [CSS3 buttons](http://css3button.net/) for illustration purposes